# Python - if or if invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I have the following line of code in Python:

```
if (sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(0,j).lower() or (if hasattr(sheet2.cell_value(2,j), 'lower'): if sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(2,j).lower())):
```

I currently get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error

The reason I try to use this `or`, `if` statements is that `sheet2.cell_value(2,j)` may not have a value in Excel (in which case it would be `#VALUE!`) in Excel. Thus, the second if in the or `sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(2,j).lower())):` must be evaluated only in case there is a value in the cell.. How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: You evidently have parentheses problems, but, what do you expect the colon in the middle to do?

Comment: what do you mean? can you be more specific? I think you need the `:` in ifs in Python...

Comment: Consider posting a simple example we can run... often times you answer your own question that way. For instance `if True or if False: pass` demonstrates the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `(if ...)` or `if ...: if ...` are both forbidden in Python.  If you want to write "condition1, and, if that's true, also condition2", just write `condition1 and condition2` (in which case `condition2` will not be evaluated if `condition1` is false).  Thus:

```
if (sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(0,j).lower() or (hasattr(sheet2.cell_value(2,j), 'lower') and sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(2,j).lower())):
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a little bit of formatting wouldn't hurt. You don't have to smash your `if` statement onto one line. Additionally, the way you have it now *is* invalid. Break your `if`s onto separate lines

Second, you have parenthesis issues. Currently, the parenthesis are going across statements (through the colon).

This block aligns the parenthesis. I removed the ones surrounding the entire statement. Instead, we have your first `or` conditional. If that evaluates to `True`, then we do your second equality check. If that passes, the rest of your logic goes into that block.

```
if sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(0,j).lower() or  hasattr(sheet2.cell_value(2,j), 'lower'): 
    if sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(2,j).lower():
        # Do stuff here
```

Comment: I still get  an error with your code:   `if sheet1.cell_value(i,8).lower()==sheet2.cell_value(0,j).lower() or (if hasattr(sheet2.cell_value(2,j), 'lower')): 
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @adrCoder, I missed another `if` in there. Check the update to see. You need to remove the `or (if...)` so that it is only `or hasattr(...)`